# Learning Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, loops, dynamic

I am trying to learn dynamic SQL

I have set up a basic example and I am stuck, I don't understand why the @Month Variable wont update with each loop.

Here is the example I made:

```
declare @M int = 1
declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
declare @Cnt int = 1
declare @Month varchar(25) = (datename(m, '2016-' + convert(varchar(2), @M) + '-01'))

while @Cnt <= 12
begin
    set @SQL = @SQL + 'select ' + convert(varchar(25), @M) + ' as M, ''' + @Month + ''' as Month'
    if  @Cnt <> 12 set @SQL = @SQL + ' Union All '  
    set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    set @M = @M + 1
end

 exec  (@SQL)
```

The results :

```
M   Month
1   January
2   January
3   January
4   January
5   January
6   January
7   January
8   January
9   January
10  January
11  January
12  January
```

I am looking to generate the the MonthName from January to December

Why does the Month Name not Update Each loop? 
Driving me mad and I cant wait until I get to work tomorrow to ask my Boss. Need to sleep tonight.

much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the SQL that is produced and include it in the question.  I'm pretty sure that if you print out `@SQL` the problem will be obvious.

Comment: Here is the output Query,  Its not so obvious to me..                                                                 select 1 as M, 'January' as Month 
Union All 
select 2 as M, 'January' as Month 
Union All 
select 3 as M, 'January' as Month 
Union All 
select 4 as M, 'January' as Month 
Union All .... etc I Dont know why the @Month is not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you advanced the @m. but not the name of the month:

```
declare @M int = 0
declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
declare @Cnt int = 1
declare @Month varchar(25) 

while @Cnt <= 12
begin
    set @M = @M + 1
    set @Month = datename(m, '2016-' + convert(varchar(2), @M) + '-01')
    set @SQL = @SQL + 'select ' + convert(varchar(25), @M) + ' as M, ''' + @Month + ''' as Month'
    if  @Cnt <> 12 set @SQL = @SQL + ' Union All '  
    set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1



end

 exec  (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add date every time in loop just like a @M variable. take another variable for date.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @Cnt int = 1
DECLARE @TempDate DateTime = Cast('2016-03-01' As DateTime)
```

Then in while loop add month

```
WHILE @Cnt <= 12
BEGIN
    set @SQL = @SQL + 'select ' + CAST(MONTH(@TempDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' as M, ''' + DateName(m,@TempDate) + ''' as Month '
    IF  @Cnt <> 12 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' Union All ' 
    SET @TempDate = DateAdd(m, @Cnt, @TempDate)
    SET @Cnt = @Cnt +1
END

EXEC  (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working with @Month inside WHILE, here is the code you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @M INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Cnt INT = 1
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(25)

WHILE @Cnt <= 12
    BEGIN
        SET @Month = ( DATENAME(m, '2016-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @M) + '-01') )

        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'select ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @M) + ' as M, ''' + @Month + ''' as Month'
        IF @Cnt <> 12
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' Union All '  



        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
        SET @M = @M + 1
    END

EXEC  (@SQL)
```